# How can I transfer my saved progress in DiRT 2 to a different mac?

Tags: macos, dirt-2

I literally spent the last 2 hours trying to find the solution, but couldn't. There are solutions for Windows, but no Mac. I basically installed DiRT 2 on my macbook pro, but already had some progress on iMac, which I would like to transfer to the new set up.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: you'll probably have to find out where ever the save files are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its in "Your HD" > Library > Application Support > Feral Interactive > Dirt 2 > Savegame

I've just had the same thing as you, trying to transfer a game save from one machine to another and I found nothing on the internet about it for a Mac. A little look in the Library folder had the answer.

Hope this works for you too.

Comment: That's exactly what I found right before you answered. I found it inside of Contents in README of how to uninstall. THanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded it from the Mac App Store, your preferences are in a different place. They are in /Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/Containers/com.feralinteractive.grid/Data/Library/Application Support/Feral Interactive/GRID

But the easiest way to get there is from the settings box that comes up when you first launch the program. (If it goes right into the game, hold down the Command key when you launch Grid to get the settings box to open.) Then click the About tab, then Open Preferences Folder. It will open a Finder window right to your settings.